# My website http://www.alfarestents.com/ to https://www.alfarestents.com/ redirection doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

http://www. version of my doesn't get redirected to https version (all other variants are properly redirected)

Website url:

http://www.alfarestents.com/
https://www.alfarestents.com/

Htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alfarestents.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.alfarestents.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Olsen. I have edited the content

Comment: The issue is the first condition pattern `^[^.]+\.[^.]+$` which will not accept a host name with _two_ dots. Just enhance it to something like `^(www\.)?[^.]+\.[^.]+$`

Comment: There are some other strange details here, I actually would expect none of those rules to work. Looks to me like you implemented endless loops... Shouldn't the second condition contain a negation? And what sense should the second rewriting rule make at all?

Comment: @arkascha thank you,  let me make the changes and try again.

Comment: @arkascha i tried with my limited knowledge. changed the initial code as below^(www\.)?[^.]+\.[^.]+$

Comment: And, what has been the result of that attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start this from scratch:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,END]
```

It probably is a good idea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as expected.

You should implement such rules in the real http server's host configuration. You can also use a distributed configuration file, but that comes with a performance penalty. Also you need to enable the consideration of such files first.